# Target tablet and mobile devices with media query

Tags: css, html, media-queries

I want to hide specific elements on my page for tablet and mobile devices. So I used:

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {

.popup_overlay {
    display:none !important;
}
}
```

Problem appears when I open the web page from my mobile which has a resolution 1920x1080 and the element appears but its not displayed correctly as the div is not optimized for small screens.

Any suggestions how to do this the proper way?

Comment: I think you will need JS

Answer (score 0):

You can add to your media query to target very high pixel density phones and tablets with min-resolution and device-pixel ratio.

See more about that here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/